# ¿Cómo eliminar una línea concreta de un fichero txt con Python?

Tags: python

Necesito leer un fichero en Python, encontrar cierto string (cada linea tiene un string) y borrarlo de dicho fichero.

He tratado de pasar el fichero original a una lista, recorrerla y extraerlo con un bucle y `readlines()`, pero luego no soy capaz de volver a meter la lista en el fichero para que me quede todo igual pero habiendo quitado cierta linea.

Es decir, si el fichero original era

```
vm1
vm2
vm3
vm4
```

y yo quiero buscar el string *vm2* y eliminarlo, necesito que me quede:

```
vm1
vm3
vm4
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Podrías hacerlo mejor a nivel de DataFrame, cargas el archivo texto a un DataFrame, retiras las lineas y estas lineas las metes a otro DataFrame. Luego vuelcas los dataframes a los archivos de texto. Al margen que el DataFrame tiene funciones de busqueda que te facilitan las cosas.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es cierra el archivo, lo vuelves a abrir en modo sobrescritura: "w", despues recorrer la lista por medio de un bucle y escribir el item actual por medio de la funcion writeln. y listo. Nota si añades tu intento podemos adaptar la respuesta a tu codigo